# Showing Cells in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xcode7, uicollectionviewcell

I have tried to make a UICollectionViewController where I can show a image for each cell. When I want to open this ViewController it shows me an error

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class RodelCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var personService: PersonService!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    assert(personService != nil, "Person Service has to be set, otherwise this class can't do anything useful.")
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return personService.allPersons().count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PersonCollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if let rodelCollectionViewCell = cell as? RodelCollectionViewCell {
        rodelCollectionViewCell.personView?.person = personService.allPersons()[indexPath.item]
    }

    return cell
}

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let PersonDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? PersonDetailViewController,
        let person = (sender as? RodelCollectionViewCell)?.personView?.person {
        PersonDetailViewController.person = person
    }
}
```

This is the error[image: /Users/ritscher/Desktop/Bildschirmfoto 2016-03-28 um 13.15.42.png]

I have tried a lot to fix it but it allways shows me the same error. I don't know where I have to solve this

Comment: Put your error in text instead of image is easier for other to help you

Comment: what return in personService.allPersons().count ? , breakpoint it and check if the data is correct in the array

Comment: What's is the error in the console log?

Comment: 1. how can I copy an error?   2. Sorry, I don't get it where I can see what data is in the array.   3. The only error is the one in the picture, in the console log is only a "(lldb)"

Comment: This piece of code `personService.allPersons()[indexPath.item]` is returning nil, so you have to validate before.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't has any information in the array. It should take the infos of all persons from the other class where I defined who the persons are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another problem** which is found with your code is in the

```
 self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Here you are trying to register a default UICollectionViewCell and in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you are trying to check for the

```
if let rodelCollectionViewCell = cell as? RodelCollectionViewCell {
    rodelCollectionViewCell.personView?.person = personService.allPersons()[indexPath.item]
}
```

Here in this code you are checking for your custom cell how this cell become custom cell

if you want to register and create your **custom cell** your should be like this:

At `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(RodelCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

At `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RodelCollectionViewCell
```

**Default cell**
If you want to keep the default cell your code will remain same as it's currently but it will not go inside the condition of custom cell ***the cell may be show empty*** if you don't do anything else in the `cellforrow`

---

**Update** 
Put both of the code in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` 
To change cell background color

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

As person view is coming nil for now as testing purpose we can add a sample view

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PersonCollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if let rodelCollectionViewCell = cell as? RodelCollectionViewCell {
        rodelCollectionViewCell.personView?.person = personService.allPersons()[indexPath.row]
    }
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
   let lbl = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,21))
   lbl.text = "\(indexPath.row)" //replace this value with your original value if it displays for the first time
   cell.contentView.addSubview(lbl)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have changed that. But it still shows only a black screen without any informations

Comment: I'm using a custom cell. where can I see this information when I have set a breakpoint there?

Comment: in the left console it shows me persons = 21 values

Comment: Ok so are you saying in the `allPersons ` or in the `self.personService.allPersons()` you got 21 , in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath ` what is the `rodelCollectionViewCell.personView?.person ` some view ? if you can check the value inside it or if you can put the some background color it will be great in narrowing the issue

Comment: the personView is nil. How can I change the background? Sorry, for all this basic things

Comment: sorry, where do I have to put the let lbl? and what do I have to write instead of the index path?

Comment: But the colour helped. Now I see the cells, but they have nothing inside

Comment: Now its the same error then in the beginning of my question

Comment: Sorry forget to update that line in your code  you have replaced the label text with your original code ? try this  `personService.allPersons()[indexPath.row]` ? , it will give you the particular object from the person array then you can use that to display any property,

Comment: Yeah, but the error is before this command. But lbl has now to memebers both = nil

Comment: as per image in your question the crash is on the same line where you are getting item from arrPerson(), also i didn't get what are saying in the last comment ? do you get member object but they are nil ?

Comment: thats true it's this error. I wanted to say that it shows me two objects for lbl. It shows me this: Printing description of lbl:
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107570/discussion-between-pyro-and-thobbit).

Comment: Does your issue are solved with the solutions from chat?

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. It's now all working fine. I have to change the size of the pictures, so they fit in the cell, but this I will get on my own. Thank you again for your time and help

Comment: you are welcome and i am glad i was able to help you

Answer (score 3):

Did you assign the cell identifier ("PersonCollectionCell") to the cell in the xib file or in the storyboard?

I noticed you declared `private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"` that you use to register the cell. But you are using a different reuseIdentifier `"PersonCollectionCell"` when dequeuing the cell.

#### Also,

I wouldn't recommend using a function `personService.allPersons()` inside:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

This method gets called every time a cell will be reuse/dequeued and could bring performance issues in the future. Instead I would save the result inside an array and update it every time something change and can affect what `personService.allPersons()` returns.

I would declared a lazy variable like this:

```
private lazy var allPersons: [WhateverTheTypeIs] = {
    let allPersons = self.personService.allPersons()
    return allPersons
}
```

and in the collectionView datasource methods use `allPersons` instead of the method itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, the first part of your answer helped. It doesn't show an error anymore. But how should I define the number of cells, if I don't use personService.allPersons()? And now it only shows a black screen instead of the CollectionView

Comment: When does `personService.allPersons()` changes the data that returns?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean but the data comes from an other class

Comment: Ok, what does that function returns?

Comment: It should return all infos of the persons I declared before

Comment: So, all the info of the persons, are entered/inserted outside of this view, right? 
Therefore, every time you call the method (while in this view) the return values will be the same. Take a look at my edit